# Swift - Capacity Storage of an Int

Tags: swift

```
var OGM = [5449000131805,5449000050205,3174780000431,5449000053565...]
```

I store about 3400 numbers in my var of type `Int`.

Is there a limite storage?
I have this message when I try to archive:

> (Xcode) encountered read error on command output pipe (Bad file descriptor)

Comment: What does that line of code have to do with the error when trying to archive?

Comment: I don't know, but when I delete my var OGM I don't have any problem to archive

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by a maximum of 255? Why do you believe this line of code is related to this error? Are you building for 64-bit or 32-bit platforms (or both)? (These numbers would overflow on 32-bit platforms).

Comment: And why are you hardcoding so many numbers into your code? Why not put the data into a data file of some kind and load the data at runtime?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm building for 64-bit only

Comment: It is possible to store "5449000131805" in a INT, isn't it?

Comment: Not on a 32-bit platform. Int32.max is 2147483647. `Int` just means "an integer of the local word size."

Comment: Fun fact, those are all Coke upc numbers

Comment: Yeah, but I store all upc numbers drinks ^_^

Comment: @rmaddy if you have time, to help me to understand your solution, I'm here to learn happily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're building for a 32-bit platform. These numbers are larger than a 32-bit Int, so that wouldn't compile, and the error you're reading may actually be some side-effect of that.

If you need to store 64-bit integers on a 32-bit platform, you need to ask for that:

```
var OGM: [Int64] = [5449000131805,5449000050205,3174780000431,5449000053565...]
```

This will likely cause other parts of your code to need specific `Int64` annotations. In many places, Swift will handle it for you, but in some cases it may not.

Comment: For information I build for 64-bit only, but Xcode doesn't accept it without your solution. I didn't understand but there was a link between the message error and my mistake !